# Google Apps Script as Web App: problems with doPost()

Tags: wordpress, google-apps-script

Ultimately I want to post some data to my App Script from my Wordpress site.
This is the endpoint of one of my test deployments: https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxW3tb8htk3tm7J3YDDOf40yK17bdSryiJDkbbyqTA1eWodCw5TRZxW0vE1KMe66yR7hw/exec

My `doGet` and `doPost`, in `doPost` I am trying to save the request parameters into a cell for debug purpose:

```
function doPost(request){
   var parameters = request.parameters;
   console.log(parameters);
   var data = JSON.stringify(parameters);
   courseSheet.getRange("D" + (courseSheet.getLastRow() + 1 )).setValue(data);
   return ContentService.createTextOutput(data);
}

function doGet(e){
  var parameters = e.parameters;
  console.log(parameters);
  var data = JSON.stringify(parameters);
  return  ContentService.createTextOutput(data);
}
```

And this is the PHP code in WP, note that `wDebug` is a custom function I use to convert the object to json string and save into the log files.

```
$body = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'time' => '2pm'
);
$api_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxW3tb8htk3tm7J3YDDOf40yK17bdSryiJDkbbyqTA1eWodCw5TRZxW0vE1KMe66yR7hw/exec";
$response = wp_remote_post($api_url, array(
  'headers'     => array(),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'body' => $body
));

if ( is_wp_error( $response ) ) {
  $error_message = $response->get_error_message();
  wDebug($error_message,true,true,'error.log');
  // Handle the error appropriately
} else {
  $response_body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
  // Handle the response body appropriately
}
wDebug($response_body,true,true,'responses.log');
```

When running the code above, the cell gets the correct value `{"time":["2pm"],"name":["John"]}`. However, I don't know what went wrong but the screenshot below shows what I get in `responses.log` file . Looks like a "400:Bad Request" has been returned.

[image]

**Q1: Why isn't this error get caught by `id_wp_error`?**

**Q2: If there is a 400 error, why my `doPost` function correctly gets the POST body and update the cell with its value?**

To further test this issue, I've tried to use javascript to post the same data to my API by executing the code below in console:

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({ name: 'John', time: '2pm' })
})
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

It returns `{}`, and the cell in my sheet also gets this `{}`.

```
$.post(url, { 
  name: "John", 
  time: "2pm" 
}, 
function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

Then I tried jQuery as above. This time everything is fine: it returns the object in console, and the cell also gets the correct value.

I think the problem here is the `header`. My guess is jQuery.post probably construct a robust header by default so it is the only one that doesn't get any error. I checked with chatgpt and it says the default header for `jQuery.post` is

```
'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

So I change my fetch code to

```
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  },
  body: 'name=John&time=2pm'
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

This time it works fine. Corrent value returns and the cell also gets the correct value.

Then I go to my PHP and change it to

```
$body = array(
    'name' => 'John',
    'time' => '2pm'
);
$api_url = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxW3tb8htk3tm7J3YDDOf40yK17bdSryiJDkbbyqTA1eWodCw5TRZxW0vE1KMe66yR7hw/exec";
$response = wp_remote_post($api_url, array(
  'headers'     => array(
    'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
  ),
  'method' => 'POST',
  'body' => $body
));
```

However, the response still says `400: Bad Request` error, although the cell still gets the right value.

I am stuck at this point. My guess is I missed something in the header when sending the POST request via PHP.

**Q3: what could be missing?**

Not only this, according to chatgpt, I probably have to set Mimetype and Header  in my `doPost` so that it can work well with my external request senders. This adds to the complexity of the whole issue. So

**Q4: Should I consider setting mimeType and Header when I just want my API to return json data? What if I want my API to return an image blob?**

Answer (score 0):

script.google.com responds to this request with a 302 redirect.
wp_remote_post handles 302 redirects as if it was 307, but google script servers expects the response to be handled as if it was a 303 redirect.
browsers do handle 302 redirects as 303 (as expected by google script servers)
here is a workaround that works for me:

```
$response = wp_remote_post($api_url, array(
  'redirection' => 0,
  'body' => $body
));
$headers = wp_remote_retrieve_headers($response);
if (isset($headers['location'])) $response = wp_remote_get($headers['location']);
$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
```