# Setting Countent-type to JSON when POST could trigger CORS block?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-apps-script, post, http-headers

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxMPbzaWcCl1HqVMuiCmxUK-UtzXg4OdQEV3gON6rPszbkGrEzwNPJFN4qJxjT1b7KN-Q/exec

Above is the endpoint of a web app deployed by Google App Script. For test purpose, it just returns the request body. I am using `fetch` in console to test it

```
  fetch(url2, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
     },
     body: 'name=John&time=2pm'
  })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data))
  .catch(error => console.error(error));
```

It returns correctly

```
{"name":["John"],"time":["2pm"]}
```

However, when I change the content-type to json

```
fetch(url2, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: 'name=John&time=2pm'
})
.then(response => response.text())
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(error => console.error(error));
```

I am getting this error:

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxMPbzaWcCl1HqVMuiCmxUK-UtzXg4OdQEV3gON6rPszbkGrEzwNPJFN4qJxjT1b7KN-Q/exec'
> from origin 'https://example.org' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
> 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's
> mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled. VM197:1
> POST https

Why is this? Is this a common behavior or it is related with Google's configuration?

P.S. This is in part of my effort to turn my App Script to an API which my wordpress site can access. Related question: [Google Apps Script as Web App: problems with doPost()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75568769/google-apps-script-as-web-app-problems-with-dopost)

Comment: Ya some of the answers help. https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin This reference is what I am looking for.

Comment: your body has to be json stringified data for #2. The cors issue is from the error handler most likely